# I have restricted the username to numerical format but not able to integrate the same with PeepSo plugin

Tags: user-registration, username

on my website i am using PeepSo Plugin and the restriction i put on wordpress signup page for username is not working on PeepSo Plugin.
my site have two registration page one is the default wordpress registration page and other one is PeepSo plugin registration page, my restriction works well on wordpress registration page but not works on PeepSo Plugin.

i am sorry as i have very less knowledge and i am learning so not able to describe it properly.

Comment: what is the actual question? where is your code? Please edit your question, make it something that can actually be answered ;)

Comment: i am sorry as i have very less knowledge and i am learning so not able to describe it properly. i can call if someone can provide a contact no to describe my issue, i am not much of technical but really want to learn @mark-kaplun

Comment: @MarkKaplun please see my answer and guide me if it was the right way to do it because i got the result i was looking for but as i am learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MarkKaplun i have figured it out with some experiment and got success in it (i have to re-install everything like 3 times). i would really appreciate if you can guide me weather i have taken the right path or not.

Here is what i did:

following is the file path in my plugin directory - /wp-content/plugins/peepso-core/classes
there are two file and both need edits.

Step 1. file name is formvalidate.php , i don't know the row no but there was written:

'username' => __('This field only accepts alpha, numbers, dashes and undersocre', 'peepso-core')

so i changed this row into:

'username' => __('This field only accepts numbers', 'peepso-core'),

Step 2. file name is register.php , in this file i had this code:

'username' => array(
                'label' => __('User Name', 'peepso-core'),
                'descript' => __('Enter your desired User Name', 'peepso-core'),
                'value' => $input->val('username', ''),
                'required' => 1,
                'validation' => array(
                    'username',
                    'required',
                    'minlen:' . PeepSoUser::USERNAME_MINLEN,
                    'maxlen:' . PeepSoUser::USERNAME_MAXLEN,
                    'custom'
                ),

i just changed it to following:

'username' => array(
                'label' => __('User Name', 'peepso-core'),
                'descript' => __('Enter your desired User Name', 'peepso-core'),
                'value' => $input->val('username', ''),
                'required' => 1,
                'validation' => array(
                    'numeric',
                    'required',
                    'minlen:' . PeepSoUser::USERNAME_MINLEN,
                    'maxlen:' . PeepSoUser::USERNAME_MAXLEN,
                    'custom'
                ),

that's it and i am able to achieve where a person can signup with numeric ID only in PeepSo Plugin.

also to do a new experiment i have changed the minimum length of user id to 10 so that anyone can create username in numaric and it can be a mobile no.
i have done following to change the minimum length :

file name - user.php just changed the

const USERNAME_MINLEN = 2; to const USERNAME_MINLEN = 10;